# Most frequent users list is unreliable

Tags: feature-request, chat

Generally speaking, the most frequent users list in the chat is rather unreliable. What I'd really appreciate is to be based on the time expended over, say, the last month, so the list is more stable. Right now the bottom half of the list can fluctuate rather badly, and we would really appreciate more stable info to base our room ownership on.

Comment: Where "our room" is the [Lounge<C++>](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec).